# ObjectResult<Nullable<System.DateTime>> does not getting stored procedure result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, stored-functions

i am using stored procedure in asp mvc

i have stored procedure function that return objectresult

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<System.DateTime>> abc()
{
}
```

when i execute in sql server it return the result but when i execute in asp mvc it does not return value

```
abcContext db = new abcContext();
ObjectResult<Nullable<DateTime>> listabc = db.abc();
```

there is no compilation error but does not getting any result also please guide me.

**Note- this is piece of code**

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "not getting any result" ? Is it null or empty sequence?

Comment: it solved thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
abcContext db = new abcContext();
var result = db.abc().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not give the list we have to iterate it using ToList method.

```
abcContext db = new abcContext();
ObjectResult<Nullable<DateTime>> listabc = db.abc().ToList();
```